Запятая между "И тогда даже"
И тогда даже в таких ситуациях получится решить проблему.
Нужна ли запятая между "тогда" и "даже"? Получится так: И тогда, даже в таких ситуациях, получится решить проблему.

Не нужны запятые. Но если очень просится, то ставьте - ошибкой не будет. А -  авторский как бы акцент, интонационный.
Корректорская поговорка: а чего их плодить-то?
